# jquery nth selector, alternating color but not using odd and even selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html table with class .myTable and I want to alternate its rows by hitting each table row by it's index (not using even and odd selector)

I have

```
$(".myTable tr.dtal").eq(0).css("background-color", "#505050");
$(".myTable tr.dtal").eq(1).css("background-color", "#2a2a2a");
$(".myTable tr.dtal").eq(2).css("background-color", "#505050");
$(".myTable tr.dtal").eq(3).css("background-color", "#2a2a2a");
$(".myTable tr.dtal").eq(4).css("background-color", "#505050");
$(".myTable tr.dtal").eq(5).css("background-color", "#2a2a2a");
$(".myTable tr.dtal").eq(6).css("background-color", "#505050");
$(".myTable tr.dtal").eq(7).css("background-color", "#2a2a2a");
$(".myTable tr.dtal").eq(8).css("background-color", "#505050");
$(".myTable tr.dtal").eq(9).css("background-color", "#2a2a2a");
```

I'm counting table rows

```
var allRows = $('.myTable tbody tr.dtal').length);
```

so how can I using loop apply this bg colors programmatically (not using even and odd jquery selector)?

Comment: _Why_ would you not want to use odd/even …?

Comment: cause I'm having some legacy code, with bug in rendering this html table. I want to hit directly every row and to finish with that. I know it's easier using odd even

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wit `odd` / `even` (I don't see what is wrong with it)

```
$(".myTable tr.dtal:odd").css({"background-color": "#505050"});
$(".myTable tr.dtal:even").css({"background-color": "#2a2a2a"});
```

Otherwise

```
$(".myTable tr.dtal").each(function (idx, domEl) { // iterate over the matched set
    var color = idx%2 ? "#505050":"#2a2a2a";    // if idx is odd: "#505050" otherwise "#2a2a2a"
    $(domEl).css({                                 // apply the css
        "background-color": color
    });
});
```

See the documentation on [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each)

Answer (score 1):

```
// Loop through each matching element
$(".myTable tr.dtal").each(function(index) {

    var 
        // Check whether index is even or odd
        indexIsEven = index % 2 === 0

        // Set background color based on whether our index is even or odd
        bg = indexIsEven  ? '#505050' : '#2a2a2a'
    ;

    // Set the backgroundColor of our element to our background color variable
    $(this).css({ backgroundColor: bg });

});
```

Which can be condensed down into:

```
$(".myTable tr.dtal").each(function(i) {
    $(this).css({ backgroundColor: index % 2 === 0? '#505050' : '#2a2a2a' });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each) method to go through each element, check the index, and apply style accordingly

```
var fColor = "#505050";
var sColor = "#2a2a2a";
$(".myTable tr.dtal").each(function(index,ele){
   $(this).css("background-color", index%2 > 0 ? sColor : fColor);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
$(".myTable tr.dtal:nth-child(2n+1)").css("background-color", "#505050");
$(".myTable tr.dtal:nth-child(2n+2)").css("background-color", "#2a2a2a");
```

or:

```
$(".myTable tr.dtal").each(function(index){
  var color = (index % 2 == 0) ? "#2a2a2a" : "#505050";
  $(this).css("background-color", color );
});
```